# Getting graphical spikes in ggplot2

Tags: r, graph, plot, ggplot2

I'm trying to plot a simple graph that show the increase in wealth for two different investment strategies. When using the standard graph from R it works, but when I try to use ggplot2 I get these weird spikes in the lines.

[image]

[image]

Does any have any idea what could be causing this?

I've tried to simply the code as much as possible:

#### For the standard graph

```
 ind.ts = ts(cbind(ind.passive,ind.active), start=c(insample.endstart,1),frequency=12)
plot(log(ind.ts),type="lines", col=c("blue","red"))
legend(x="topleft", legend=c("Passive","Active"), col=c("blue","red"), lty=1)
```

#### For the ggplot graph

```
  testers=data.frame(ind.ts)
ggplot(testers, aes(date)) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = log(ind.passive), colour = "Passive",size="1")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y = log(ind.active), colour = "Active",size="1"))
```

#### The Ind.ts data set

```
structure(c(1, 1.026669, 1.066102329621, 1.09764083483818, 1.13073909657189, 
1.17422279926966, 1.201650295415, 1.24229131005623, 1.24436842112664, 
1.29675757602449, 1.29281154272065, 1.34840890311535, 1.37447769243928, 
1.42187380670767, 1.43432089001159, 1.44828830683852, 1.47037760009442, 
1.50663270057995, 1.51269991046518, 1.44617893190248, 1.47609892782461, 
1.55880475075062, 1.60230787373457, 1.72267003659376, 1.6884336922865, 
1.7947931958647, 1.80827747714523, 1.73407842742553, 1.83823238001199, 
1.94879470474019, 2.03637158997651, 2.19836698633073, 2.07500122615881, 
2.18823196806907, 2.11573803119891, 2.21303659177769, 2.25083083069207, 
2.27667036862841, 2.44006700098487, 2.56495939036328, 2.59127330874902, 
2.54554769994283, 2.64902166839781, 2.62135793511473, 2.24229384954953, 
2.38534322797539, 2.58003017155629, 2.73574015247005, 2.89313822640227, 
3.01496249083961, 2.92082933195062, 3.03735873897812, 3.15584610338566, 
3.08028252428619, 3.25121048184135, 3.15027015001163, 3.13383204036887, 
3.04763285626648, 3.24152630621501, 3.30661615444381, 3.5011906754359, 
3.32628169286315, 3.26271977599422, 3.58162126961968, 3.47465973202375, 
3.4018482373392, 3.48660188432426, 3.43296051433394, 3.64465402445034, 
3.45302176049876, 3.43920276741325, 3.16710336206381, 3.18321124976327, 
3.29673729577483, 2.9957319937214, 2.80662641161774, 3.02543381329387, 
3.04403720581181, 2.97111425050939, 2.94227958670819, 2.75683358891715, 
2.53472102032527, 2.58379068455775, 2.78122846592754, 2.80549468429276, 
2.76500859050373, 2.71079783207832, 2.81360212906206, 2.64401226073284, 
2.62324090041252, 2.43641368348514, 2.24723834303094, 2.26148583412576, 
2.01595857860056, 2.19346574740491, 2.32192606890168, 2.18514140418268, 
2.12856372294559, 2.09571359900937, 2.1165869064555, 2.29149953181808, 
2.41150994529845, 2.44221328992199, 2.48518647497146, 2.53301388868229, 
2.50620193667058, 2.64742390960003, 2.6698343529948, 2.80897010046677, 
2.86115795596334, 2.89979789415863, 2.85611823847891, 2.81197121886675, 
2.84980347964538, 2.90496997540435, 2.80930350417434, 2.81972040156782, 
2.85016210302314, 2.89418855702854, 3.00999951213804, 3.11183381563269, 
3.03729294841303, 3.09892873421517, 3.04396923311387, 2.98710484387007, 
3.08097760069353, 3.08499827646243, 3.20047593194697, 3.16912086924169, 
3.19575099190593, 3.14371138275373, 3.25904157854143, 3.26071346687123, 
3.3485896948034, 3.35499219829987, 3.3971510302637, 3.44342702159796, 
3.34200432210381, 3.3473849490624, 3.36955802696499, 3.4464479715823, 
3.53637269205683, 3.65311189099431, 3.71864871831875, 3.7710110109214, 
3.82954087282191, 3.75144504580245, 3.79450413203817, 3.96444479409563, 
4.09921609487092, 4.03197255405065, 3.90887240000293, 3.96507025849778, 
4.11298323942078, 4.18000430130714, 4.00202389816178, 3.973681564915, 
3.73688988046171, 3.6132997214452, 3.59812747591486, 3.77562310430174, 
3.82238042082541, 3.50029900180582, 3.47233161278139, 3.52122551422096, 
3.20811814149644, 2.67119786498117, 2.47785656351383, 2.50381211101664, 
2.29590056094204, 2.04999813136234, 2.23149881591877, 2.44744541933286, 
2.58359925545577, 2.59022877114527, 2.78828284344458, 2.88774646903593, 
2.99667515359443, 2.94310059519847, 3.1174675330616, 3.17829867703423, 
3.06610473373492, 3.15882374088307, 3.34981254190434, 3.40448483240076, 
3.13064849939144, 2.96722864772321, 3.17659630110655, 3.0311907820197, 
3.30193068028814, 3.42901538831107, 3.42659107443153, 3.65581631094671, 
3.74411158648869, 1, 1.026669, 1.066102329621, 1.09764083483818, 
1.13073909657189, 1.17422279926966, 1.201650295415, 1.24229131005623, 
1.24436842112664, 1.29675757602449, 1.29281154272065, 1.34840890311535, 
1.37447769243928, 1.42187380670767, 1.43432089001159, 1.44828830683852, 
1.47037760009442, 1.50663270057995, 1.51269991046518, 1.44617893190248, 
1.47609892782461, 1.55880475075062, 1.60230787373457, 1.72267003659376, 
1.6884336922865, 1.7947931958647, 1.80827747714523, 1.73407842742553, 
1.83823238001199, 1.94879470474019, 2.03637158997651, 2.19836698633073, 
2.07500122615881, 2.18823196806907, 2.11573803119891, 2.21303659177769, 
2.25083083069207, 2.27667036862841, 2.44006700098487, 2.56495939036328, 
2.59127330874902, 2.54554769994283, 2.64902166839781, 2.62135793511473, 
2.24229384954953, 2.2509042579318, 2.25833224198298, 2.39462710945113, 
2.53239958556629, 2.63903386731532, 2.55663795191, 2.6586375796394, 
2.76235103162114, 2.69620929852, 2.84582464870417, 2.75747033083585, 
2.74308185064955, 2.66763064126559, 2.83734797029354, 2.89432191753704, 
3.06463539645259, 2.91153540595201, 2.85589887587967, 3.13503728790702, 
3.04141253434097, 2.97767973468385, 3.05186564759377, 3.00491269460554, 
3.19021063591839, 3.02247255089243, 3.01037661574376, 3.02584995154869, 
3.04040428981563, 3.05344762421894, 3.06587515604951, 3.07715757662378, 
3.08709679559627, 3.09641982791897, 3.10543040961822, 3.1145293207184, 
3.12325000281641, 3.13012115282261, 3.13575537089769, 3.14064714927629, 
3.14507546175677, 3.14941566589399, 3.15395082445288, 3.15865021118131, 
2.96826256970236, 2.97253686780273, 2.97675787015501, 2.98092533117323, 
2.98494958037031, 2.98900911179961, 2.99295460382719, 2.99603734706913, 
2.99900342404273, 3.00194244739829, 3.00488435099674, 3.00770894228668, 
3.01053618869243, 3.16820398996663, 3.20854156316688, 3.26499906051237, 
3.32783396743193, 3.29260884488666, 3.47814406068718, 3.5075865501609, 
3.69038091563598, 3.75894450266758, 3.80970904817611, 3.75232340078343, 
3.69432373797752, 3.74402716954827, 3.81650404749639, 3.69081893620424, 
3.70450449281968, 3.74449832332416, 3.80233958892455, 3.95449020757537, 
4.08827852027806, 3.99034789660332, 4.07132402646909, 3.99911909485966, 
3.92441155104859, 4.04774010845184, 4.05302240929337, 4.20473514411804, 
4.16354135391111, 4.19852759190803, 4.1301587686014, 4.28167777318631, 
4.28387427388395, 4.39932468556512, 4.40773619436392, 4.4631238073823, 
4.52392047988646, 4.39067292607189, 4.39774190948286, 4.42687255189128, 
4.52788935665288, 4.64603104574667, 4.79940117659781, 4.88550243370598, 
4.95429519347499, 5.03119080917292, 4.92858973500145, 4.9851600879798, 
5.20842546768007, 5.38548589145385, 5.29714238089044, 5.13541532685947, 
5.20924719301373, 5.40357295030192, 5.49162417152709, 5.25779630592764, 
5.22056059248906, 4.90946738678263, 4.91815714405724, 4.9233212090585, 
4.92863839596428, 4.93573563525447, 4.94338602548911, 4.95010903048378, 
4.95718768639737, 4.96184744282258, 4.96462607739057, 4.96542041756295, 
4.96556938017547, 4.96611559280729, 4.9673571217055, 4.9682512459874, 
4.96889711864938, 4.96964245321718, 4.97038789958516, 4.9711334577701, 
5.14846373047568, 5.34266893085295, 5.24715269570716, 5.55802550431702, 
5.66647925598276, 5.46645253824657, 5.63175806300315, 5.97226541900844, 
6.06973876291208, 5.58152539525601, 5.29016976962365, 5.2908574916937, 
5.04867378086891, 5.04933010846042, 5.24366872567485, 5.2399614518858, 
5.59049391317115, 5.72551552216206), .Dim = c(194L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
NULL, c("ind.passive", "ind.active")), .Tsp = c(1995, 2011.08333333333, 
12), class = c("mts", "ts", "matrix"))
```

#### The date data set

```
structure(c(1995.1, 1995.2, 1995.3, 1995.4, 1995.5, 1995.6, 1995.7, 
1995.8, 1995.9, 1995.1, 1995.11, 1995.12, 1996.1, 1996.2, 1996.3, 
1996.4, 1996.5, 1996.6, 1996.7, 1996.8, 1996.9, 1996.1, 1996.11, 
1996.12, 1997.1, 1997.2, 1997.3, 1997.4, 1997.5, 1997.6, 1997.7, 
1997.8, 1997.9, 1997.1, 1997.11, 1997.12, 1998.1, 1998.2, 1998.3, 
1998.4, 1998.5, 1998.6, 1998.7, 1998.8, 1998.9, 1998.1, 1998.11, 
1998.12, 1999.1, 1999.2, 1999.3, 1999.4, 1999.5, 1999.6, 1999.7, 
1999.8, 1999.9, 1999.1, 1999.11, 1999.12, 2000.1, 2000.2, 2000.3, 
2000.4, 2000.5, 2000.6, 2000.7, 2000.8, 2000.9, 2000.1, 2000.11, 
2000.12, 2001.1, 2001.2, 2001.3, 2001.4, 2001.5, 2001.6, 2001.7, 
2001.8, 2001.9, 2001.1, 2001.11, 2001.12, 2002.1, 2002.2, 2002.3, 
2002.4, 2002.5, 2002.6, 2002.7, 2002.8, 2002.9, 2002.1, 2002.11, 
2002.12, 2003.1, 2003.2, 2003.3, 2003.4, 2003.5, 2003.6, 2003.7, 
2003.8, 2003.9, 2003.1, 2003.11, 2003.12, 2004.1, 2004.2, 2004.3, 
2004.4, 2004.5, 2004.6, 2004.7, 2004.8, 2004.9, 2004.1, 2004.11, 
2004.12, 2005.1, 2005.2, 2005.3, 2005.4, 2005.5, 2005.6, 2005.7, 
2005.8, 2005.9, 2005.1, 2005.11, 2005.12, 2006.1, 2006.2, 2006.3, 
2006.4, 2006.5, 2006.6, 2006.7, 2006.8, 2006.9, 2006.1, 2006.11, 
2006.12, 2007.1, 2007.2, 2007.3, 2007.4, 2007.5, 2007.6, 2007.7, 
2007.8, 2007.9, 2007.1, 2007.11, 2007.12, 2008.1, 2008.2, 2008.3, 
2008.4, 2008.5, 2008.6, 2008.7, 2008.8, 2008.9, 2008.1, 2008.11, 
2008.12, 2009.1, 2009.2, 2009.3, 2009.4, 2009.5, 2009.6, 2009.7, 
2009.8, 2009.9, 2009.1, 2009.11, 2009.12, 2010.1, 2010.2, 2010.3, 
2010.4, 2010.5, 2010.6, 2010.7, 2010.8, 2010.9, 2010.1, 2010.11, 
2010.12, 2011.1, 2011.2), .Tsp = c(1995, 2011.08333333333, 12
), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, we do not have your data, at first glance it looks like the data in the first has been smoothed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The spikes are in your data, specifically in the crummy way the dates are stored. January, February, March 1995 are coded as `1995.10, 1995.20, 1995.30`, but then October, November, and December are `1995.10, 1995.11, 1995.12`. When you pass your time series to `ggplot` you maybe saw a warning like:

> Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type ts. Defaulting to continuous

So ggplot just converted to numerics, giving October the same x value as January and inserting Nov and Dec before February, causing your spikes. Since your samples (as far as I checked) are spaced every month, you could add a new column to your data like this:

```
ind.df <- as.data.frame(ind.ts)
ind.df$date <- seq(as.Date('1995-01-01'), as.Date('2011-02-01'), by = "month")
```

Then, ggplot works best with long-format data, so we can melt it

```
library(reshape2)
ind.melt <- melt(ind.df, id.vars = "date")
ggplot(ind.melt, aes(x = date, y = value, color = variable) +
    geom_line(size = 1)
```

[image]

And the spikes are gone.

One other note, in `ggplot` don't put anything inside `aes()` that isn't mapping to a data column. In your post, inside `aes()` you have `size = "1"`. You don't need the quotes around `1`, and since it applies to the whole layer you should put it outside of `aes()`.

Answer (score 0):

The following example illustrates that for a very simple example, the plots from the basic R plotting and `ggplot2` are the same, i.e. basic plotting does not get rid of the spikes, nor does `ggplot2` introduces spikes. You need to make your example more complete, i.e. provide us with a sample of your data that reproduces the issue you see.

```
x = 1:100
y = runif(100)
y[50] = 5

plot(x, y)
```

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
qplot(x, y, geom = 'line')
```

[image]

Comment: Here is a link to the data used in the examples I provided.[Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/ygr371sa5nfm3i1/Y8VuyBDw6P)

Comment: Could you put them in your question, see the R command `dput` for how to do this. In this way, it would be much easier for someone to use your data, simply pasting it into an R session in stead of having to save the ods files, open openoffice calc, save it as `csv` and load it into R.